# How to loop through two directories ([A/{a,b,c}] & [n/{1,2,3}] at the same time to form pairs with their contents

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am not sure how to look for this, so please direct me to the answer if it's around somewhere. I also want to apologize in advance if the title of the question is not clear, I couldn't think of a better description.

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do. Let's say I have these two directories that are on different hard drives:

`A/data_dir1/` contains:

- `dir1/`
- `dir2/`
- `dir3/`
- `dir4/`

`B/info_dir1/` contains:

- `dirA/`
- `dirB/`
- `dirC/`
- `dirD/`

Now, what happens is that if they are ordered alphabetically, dir1/ and dirA/ are related, so I want to extract some files from dir1/ and copy them inside dirA/. The same happens with dir2/ and dirB/, dir3/ and dirC/, etc.

I am sure there is an easier/better/more correct/faster way to do this, but right now I am stuck on this idea and can't think of any other way, so what I am thinking of doing is to:

```
counter1=0
for info_dir in $(ls -d info_dir1/*); do
    counter1=counter1+1
    counter2=0
    for data_dir in $(ls -d data_dir1/*); do
        counter2=counter2+1
        if [[ counter1 == counter2 ]]; then
            cp $data_dir/[file2copy] $info_dir/
        fi
    done
done
```

I would be doing this on the assumption that it will always loop both folders in the right order, but I am afraid that something could go wrong. Is there any other way of doing it that I ignore?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

Make two arrays, one for each set of directories, then loop over the indexes:

```
data_dirs=( A/data_dir1/*/ )
info_dirs=( B/info_dir1/*/ )
n=${#data_dirs[@]}               # assume they're the same length
for (( i = 0; i < n; i++ )); do
    left="${data_dirs[i]}"
    right="${info_dirs[i]}"
    printf "%s <-> %s\n" "$left" "$right"
    # or whatever
done
```

The shell sorts filenames from globs lexicographically, so you should get `dirA` paired with `dir1`; and `dirB` paired with `dir2` etc. But it's probably best to double check. You don't need `ls`, it'll just be an extra process that adds nothing to the list of filenames provided by the shell. (Plus it'll break filenames that contain whitespace.)

I have no idea what "tuple-style" and the syntax "[A/a-n/1] [A/b-n/2]" are supposed to mean.

Comment: Your suggestion worked flawlessly! Thank you very much.

However, I would like to understand in a better way how the 3rd and 4th lines work. Could you please explain them a little bit or forward me to a webpage that contains that information?

Finally, sorry about the "tuple-style" and "[A/a-n/1]...". I realized they were very confusing, but I was trying to talk about the concept of "tuples" that exists in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Some ways to produce the desired pairs of directory names, given the directory structure is as described:

```
for info_dir in info_dir1/*/; do read data_dir; echo "$data_dir" "$info_dir"; done <<< $(ls -1d data_dir1/*/)
data_dir1/dir1/ info_dir1/dirA/
data_dir1/dir2/ info_dir1/dirB/
data_dir1/dir3/ info_dir1/dirC/
data_dir1/dir4/ info_dir1/dirD/
```

or

```
paste <(ls -1d data_dir1/*/) <(ls -1d info_dir1/*/)
data_dir1/dir1/ info_dir1/dirA/
data_dir1/dir2/ info_dir1/dirB/
data_dir1/dir3/ info_dir1/dirC/
data_dir1/dir4/ info_dir1/dirD/
```

or

```
{ ls -d data_dir1/*/; ls -d info_dir1/*/; } | \pr -2ts" " -
data_dir1/dir1/ info_dir1/dirA/
data_dir1/dir2/ info_dir1/dirB/
data_dir1/dir3/ info_dir1/dirC/
data_dir1/dir4/ info_dir1/dirD/
```

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`:

```
data_dirs=( A/data_dir1/*(Nn/) )
info_dirs=( B/info_dir1/*(Nn/) )
for data info in ${data_dirs:^info_dirs}; do
  something with $data and $info
done
```

Where:

- the `n` glob qualifier enables `numericglobsort` so that for instance, `dir10` sorts after `dir9` and not between `dir1` and `dir2` as it does normally in globs where the ordering is lexical.
- The `/` restricts to files of type *directory*. Change to `-/` if you also want to consider symlinks to directories.
- `${A:^B}` zips 2 arrays. If they are not of the same size, it truncates the longest to the size of the shortest. For instance, `(a b c)` zipped with `(1 2)` would give `(a 1 b 2)`.
- In `zsh`, you can loop with several variables, so `for i j in a 1 b 2` loops with i=a j=1 and then i=b j=2.